# beginner JavaScript background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having is trying to have a grey background, but with text over top of it rather than before or after the grey square.

Here is my code, an HTML document with JS and CSS integrated:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Change svg background color. */
            .area {
                background-color: #75738a;
          }
        </style>
    
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg width="2000px" height="2000px" class="area">
            <script>
                write("Power up to the top");
            </script>
        </svg>
    
        <script>
            // start game "press any to continue"
            document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {


            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is very unspecific. You should be including information about how you are rendering text and graphics to the game and any libraries you are using if applicable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was drawing a square and expecting to be able to put text on it. I realized instead of setting it to print a square, I needed to set the background image in HTML, and use CSS to center and fullscreen it.

```
<body>
    <img src="gymbackground.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
<body>
```

HTML^

```
<style>
    #bg {
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 

        /* Preserve aspet ratio */
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

CSS within HTML^